# How to detect available disk space when saving a file in browser

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, save-as, filesaver.js

I have implemented a screen recording feature into our webrtc conferencing app. (Normal MediaRecorder API)
I am using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save the recordings.

Everything is working just fine.

I was presented with a problem today!
What if user's HDD is full, what happens then?
I tested this. chrome says "Failed, File Too Large" and nothing.
File is not saved and there is no option to retry somewhere else :((

So ... is there any way to detect this somehow and prompt the user to re-download/re-save the recorded file again ?